# Running Spark Validation on EMR cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

How do I read a CSV file from S3 bucket using EMR and then perform spark validation(SSN column in the file with 10 digits is a valid) on EMR cluster so that the valid records have to store in Redshift and invalid records have to store in mongodb?

Comment: Please add information about what you have tried so far and what the specific problem is.

Comment: i written the pyspark code to read the file from s3 bucket and performed required validations.I moved that code to emr cluster using winscp then i run that code using spark-submit code name

Comment: I'm not sure whether the process is a correct approach but i got valid and invalid datframes as output. Now how can write them to redshift and Mongobdb.